# What is the best way to share Android Project without causing gradle errors?

Tags: android

I downloaded sample project to understand how fragment works from here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/fragments/fragment-ui.html.
It was very clean & didn't require any gradle configurations.

However, if I share my project with a friend, it looks very ugly with Test folders & hardcoded gradle settings.
Isn't there a way to share android project without manually configuring build settings(just like fragments sample project works) ?

Comment: What do you mean by hard-coded Gradle settings? All the settings should be relative to your project. If you make a blank app with Android Studio & Gradle, it'll be sharable

Comment: What I mean is, if I share the project with some other person, they can easily compile & run the application without manually configuring grade settings. Right now the other person has to edit build.gradle & gradle wrapper files to point to version of gradle installed on their machine.

Comment: Check the fragment project from the link for precise understanding.

Comment: Android Studio comes with its own Gradle wrapper as far as I know. Yes, everyone will need their own installation of Gradle, but that shouldn't be hard-coded.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do that. But before anything do this
gradle>build>clean (not build menu>clean)

1. #### Share project on GitHub, by exporting through Android Studio.

   This takes care of the files to be ignored while sharing the project.
   However, when other person downloads the project in zip format, branch/tag name will be appended to the name of the folder, resulting in difficulty when importing in Android Studio.
   So, after downloading zip make sure to **remove the branch/tag name from folder before importing in Android Studio**.
2. #### Create a zip, delete files from zip

   Delete following files/folders from zip before sharing.

   ```
   *.iml
   .gradle
   /local.properties
   /.idea/workspace.xml
   /.idea/libraries (this folder)
   .DS_Store
   /build
   /captures
   .git
   .gitignore
   ```